# BASH: Newline or HR after long command output

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

Is there any way to configure Bash to print a newline or horizontal line after commands that provided more than N lines of output? For instance, after a simple `cd` I don't need a newline or horizontal line, but after a long `cat` a visual indication of the end of each command's output would be great when I am comparing the output of various commands.

Comment: Maybe, I did not understand you well. If you want to add a newline, you can just use `echo` after each command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you could use a wrapper script like the one below:

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD="$*"
N=10
IFS=:

i=0;
eval $CMD | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    i=$((i+1))
    if [ $((i % $N)) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo '================================================================';
    fi
done
```

Save it in your homedir, lets say as a ~/wrapper.sh. Make alias for it in your .bashrc file:

```
alias wrap="~/wrapper.sh "
```

Now you can invoke command of your choice with 'wrap' prefix:

```
wrap cat veryLongFile
```

stdout from your command will be post-processed by the wrapper.sh (I'm adding horizontal line after each 1o lines)

Comment: That is great! Is there any way to have _all_ commands automatically wrapped?

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done in bash. The program's output to the terminal does not pass through shell (bash), so there is no way for bash to determine how many lines were printed.

Personally I just manually hit enter once or twice in case when I need visual separation. If you would like to have a newline on *every* command, the best way is to `export PS1='\n'"$PS1"`

Comment: Thank you kubanczyk. I actually do currently have a newline character there but seeing a new line after every command is a real waste of screen space. It drives me nuts like source code with the opening bracket on a line to itself.